# join head to body

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, topology

I have this situation here where I want to join this Face Builder created head to a Human Generator body.
I deleted the HG head and joined the head mesh to the body mesh but now I want to fill the remaining gap with good topology. I managed to do this in the past with ALT F and it worked quite well. After that I used some smoothing and sculpting, dissolved some vertices and it was quite all right for what I needed.
But in this case when I use Alt F it only fills half the gap and I was wondering if there is a better workflow here than counting vertices and match them manually.

I added the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lXVBhQ99AeRKo5YG0ftVo1twupSx0Xw3/view?usp=sharing) for reference if needed.

Thank you !

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best would be to have a consistent topology, between the body and head. But from what you have you could activate the *LoopTools* addon, remove the 2 first edge loops of the head, select the edges of the body and head and right click > *LoopTools > Bridge*:

[image]

Add some segments in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @moonboots! I forgot about looptools.